# How to convert hit point to pixel points for Texture2D in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, game-development, texture2d

I have a game where you need to draw something on a plane with the mouse at the finish. I am raycasting mouse position with this:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
            {
                Vector3 mousePos = hit.point;
                Draw(mousePos);
            }
        }
```

In the Draw function, I use the SetPixel method to apply my changes to the texture:

```
public void Draw(mousePos) {
    //Dont know how to use mousePos
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(128, 128);
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
    texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);
    texture.Apply();
}
```

But I could not make the conversion between Vector3 mousePosition to the (x,y) pair of texture pixel.
How can I do the conversion?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RaycastHit.textureCoord`

This will return the texture coordinate when a hit occurs.
The object being hit **MUST** have a mesh collider on it for this to work.

```
Vector2 pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;

// Convert to image space
//
pixelUV.x *= texture.width; 
pixelUV.y *= texture.height;

texture.SetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y, Color.black);
texture.Apply();
```

This example is taken from the unity documents, and is found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html)